# A view in UITabBarController disappears after a memory warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UINavigationController` within one of the tabs of a `UITabBarController`.

I now present a new view controller (let’s call it Steve) over the whole app (using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`).

Then, I simulate low memory.

After dismissing Steve (using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`), I can now see that the `UINavigationController`’s view is gone; within the tab; only an empty white area is seen!

Why is this? I have tried calling the `view` methods on all imaginable controllers upon Steve’s dismissal, but the contents of the tab still stay empty (white).

**The strange thing is this:** If I click on another tab, and click back on the original tab, the contents (the navigation controller) shows just fine again. Is the tab bar controller doing something special to force the view to display?

---

**UPDATE:** I was able to “fix” my issue with this terrible code, just before dismissing Steve:

```
[[[[[self tabBarController] view] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]
        addSubview:[[self navigationController] view]];
```

What this does is that it finds the subview of the tab bar controller which is *not* the tab bar (i.e. the top view), and then adds the navigation controller’s view to be its subview.

This is of course terrible, because it makes internal assumptions about the subview structure of the tab bar controller’s view.

If someone has any better solutions, please let me know about them.

Comment: Did you check the viewDidUnload methods of the base classes? Maybe something is removed or released there.

Comment: I have not implemented any unload methods anywhere. (I’m using ARC.)

Comment: Oh k. I will see through it again then.

Comment: Just because you are using ARC does not mean you do not need to unload things.

Comment: I have the same problem but your "fix" did not solve it. Still looking for solution...

Answer (score 0):

When your app receives a memory warning, one of the first thing it will do is drop the view hierarchies of any view controllers that have loaded views but are not currently visible (like your `UINavigationController`).  Most likely, whatever view controller is at the top of your navigation stack is having its views dropped but not reloading them when it reappears.

Always put your view construction code in `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad` and not in `-init`.  That way, the view controller will reconstruct your view if it's been dropped due to a memory warning.

(P.S.: The reason your hack works is the bit where you call `[[self navigationController] view]`, which in turn calls `-loadView` on the top VC in the stack, forcing it to reconstruct its view.)

Comment: I tried calling only `[[self navigationController] view]` as you hinted at, but that didn’t do anything. However, my hack continues to work. I’m not doing anything special in any `init` method. I set up the view hierarchy (the tab bar controller and its navigation controllers, along with table view controllers that appear within the navigation controllers) inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. Based on this new information, do you happen to have any further ideas?

Comment: @Enchilada What I mean by "view hierarchy" isn't the view controller structure so much as the views within the controller(s).  I'd need to see your table view controller code -- my hunch from earlier is that you're setting up the subviews of your TVC in the view controller's `init` method, not in `viewDidLoad`.